# Open in new tab document link item from document library

Tags: document-library, asp.net, caml

I have a document link item that points to a URL. This item is inside a document library.

Is there a way to make this item open to a new page?

I opened the aspx file it creates, but I am unsure how to modify to insert the target parameter.

```
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x01010A0093C87013D9B24B45AC8476086CC4559F</mso:ContentTypeId>
<mso:IconOverlay msdt:dt="string">||linkoverlay.gif</mso:IconOverlay>
<mso:URL msdt:dt="string">http://www.google.com</mso:URL>

</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always use jQuery to change link behavior, which would look something like this:

```
 jQuery("#myLinkID a").attr("target","_blank");
```

Reference: [how to put target=“_blank” in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933501/how-to-put-target-blank-in-jquery)

Comment: Is the id to be used in the JQuery from the OP `0x01010A0093C87013D9B24B45AC8476086CC4559F`?